# Cannot SSH into a virtual machine unless restart my computer

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware

I am using xShell to connect to my virtual machine (Ubuntu 20.10) on set up via VMware on my Windows laptop.

Every time, the connection won’t go through unless I restart my computer (I cannot ping the virtual machine from my laptop either). Sometimes, I even need to restart multiple times. I have no idea what is wrong.

I am using basic IP of the VM. I cannot ping the IP address of the VM either.

Comment: How are you SSHing? Via hostname or basic IP address of the VM?

Comment: I am using basic IP of the VM. I cannot ping the IP address of the VM either.

Comment: and where did you get the IP from? what does the console connection say when you open a terminal on your ubuntu and use `ifconfig` or `ip addr` as root?

Comment: @Zina And yet another question — but I think it makes sense — but does the VM have a static IP address? Networking for VMs can either be bridged, NAT or host-only. Knowing how that is established on your machine might shed more light on what is going on. In my experience it will be either bridged or host-only: Host only would be a local IP address like `192.168.x.x`, `172.16.x.x` or `10.x.x.x`. Bridged would be another IP address on your LAN that might have a similar address to those but is accessible on the LAN.

Comment: VMware Workstation usually on Windows creates VMnet0 (Bridged), VMnet1 (Host-Only, 192.168.x.0/24) and VMnet8 (NAT, 192.168.y.0/24) networks, and then it depends where the VM's vmnics are connected to. Of course you can add more networks... From the host itself any DHCP IP on those networks will work, so, yes, if the OP set a static IP on the VM outside those networks it will not be reachable. Could you also give us the info from the `Virtual Network Editor` window?

Comment: for VMware's VMPlayer I can't remember what it uses for networks